# Proving inductive step

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm trying to with an induction proof; for every n >= 7, n! > 3^n.

Here's what I have

```
Proof:
    Base case: n = 7. 5040>2187. Case holds for n = 7.

    Inductive Step: let n >= 7.
                    Suppose that n! > 3^n for n >= 7.
                    We want to show that (n+1)! > 3^n+1.
```

I am stuck with actually doing the math to prove that (n+1)! > 3^n+1.

Comment: You want to reduce the (n+1) case to the (n) case: $(n+1)! = (n+1)\cdot n!$ and $3^{n+1} = 3 \cdot 3^n$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Nick Your hint is much better than my answer!